# n*n array which has 2 times every random values

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, random, multidimensional-array

To randomly generate a n*n array of assorted characters such that there are exactly two of each character in PYTHON

```py
import random
import numpy as np
from string import punctuation
set(punctuation)
S = 5
char = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z',\
    'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z']
Digits = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
symbols = ['~', ':', '+', '[', '@', '^', '{', '%', '(', '-', '*', '|', '&', '<', '}',\
    '_', '=', ']', '!', '>', ';', '?', '#', '$', ')', '/']    
def create_array(n):
    s =random.choices(char + Digits + symbols)
    print(s)
    x = np.empty((n, n), dtype=object)
    if(n<=100):
        
        for i in range(n): 
            for j in range(n): 
                k =random.choices(char + Digits + symbols)
                x[i][j] = k              
        for i in range(n): 
            for j in range(n): 
                print(*x[i][j],sep=" ",end = " ")  
            print() 

n = 5

create_array(n)
```

i don't know how to assign the same value a second time

Comment: Please fix the formatting to make your code readable

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list of every element that can still be used, like this:

```
def create_array(n):
    available = char + Digits + symbols
    print(random.choices(available))
    x = np.empty((n, n), dtype=object)
    if(n<=100):
        for i in range(n): 
            for j in range(n): 
                k = random.choices(available)
                available.remove(k)
                x[i][j] = k              
        for i in range(n): 
            for j in range(n): 
                print(*x[i][j],sep=" ",end = " ")  
            print()
```

It is not the fastest solution, but it is python. If you want a fast solution, you can use a set with tuples of the element and the times it was used. I don't know if it is in fact faster for these number of elements, but it has a better runtime (O(1) instead of O(n))